# dragstart event gives error: Permission denied to access property "effectAllowed"

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, meteor, drag-and-drop

I just started to work with meteor (1.1.0.2) and try to implement some drag and drop functionality. Basically what it should do: The user can drag video element from a sidebar to a contenteditable div.

My problem is now that it is not working in firefox (v 37, OSX) but it is working in Chrome.

Here is some Code:

```js
Template.single_video.events(
{
  'dragstart video': function(event)
  {
 var dt =  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    dt.effectAllowed = "copy";
 dt.setData('text/html', event.currentTarget.outerHTML);

 return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<template name="single_video">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  {{title}} 
  <video controls="" class="video-drag" draggable="true">
   {{#each sources}}
    <source src="{{src}}" type="{{type}}">
   {{/each}}
  </video>
 </div>
</template>
```

I always get the error: **Error: Permission denied to access property "effectAllowed"**

So my question is: Is it a bug in FF or did I miss something?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I observe sth similar on IE 11 as well. Still working on it.